Cannot read properties Error while importing express
I'm trying to connect Express like this:
import express from 'express'

but the browser gives the error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')

This way
const express = require('express')

I can't connect, because I have it in the package.json "type": "module"
How to fix the error?

What version of node are you using?

@fordat v20.14.0

You can try renaming index.js to index.mjs and rename it in the corresponding package.json declarations too. This makes it explicit that you're using modern JS. You don't typically have to do this but I'm not sure what else could be wrong. I'd also try deleting node_modules and reinstalling.
